# Nested Quantifiers true or false

Tags: predicate-logic

I have a concern with nested quantifiers.

I have: $$  \forall x \exists y \forall z(x^2-y+z=0) $$ such that $$ x,y,z \in \Bbb Z^+$$

My first question, can it be read like this:

$$  \forall x \forall z \exists y(x^2-y+z=0)  $$

The way I did it, is I started off with $x=1, z=1 $

$$ 2-y = 0 $$ $$ y =2 $$

Is this a good approach?

Comment: No. The order matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot interchange the $\exists y$ and $\forall z$: doing so changes the meaning of the statement. The original statement,

$$\forall x\exists y\forall z\left(x^2-y+z=0\right)$$

says that no matter what positive integer $x$ you choose, I can find a $y\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x^2-y+z=0$ **no matter what positive integer** $z$ **you choose**. For instance, if you choose $x=1$, I can find some positive integer $y$ such that $1-y+z=0$ **for every positive integer** $z$. Since $1-y+z=0$ if and only if $z=y-1$, this is clearly false: no matter what $y$ I pick, you can choose for $z$ any positive integer except $y-1$ and ensure that $x^2-y+z$ is **not** $0$.

The modified statement

$$\forall x\forall z\exists y\left(x^2-y+z=0\right)\;,$$

on the other hand, says something very different: it says that no matter what positive integers you choose for $x$ and $z$, I can find a positive integer $y$ such that $x^2-y+z=0$. And of course I can: I just pick $y=x^2+z$.

Since one statement is true and the other false, they certainly cannot be equivalent.

Comment: reason I get so confused is choosing values for each variable and in which order. If the for loop starts at $x=1$ and choose $y=1$ as my choice, then the for loop for $z$ would start at $z=1$? If so then $(1-1+z)$ which is $z=0$ but zero in no a positive integer...right?

Comment: @Dimitri: These expressions really don’t have anything to do with FOR loops, and you shouldn’t try to think of them in those terms. Take a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401707/true-or-false-statements-odd-integers) and my answer to it, and see whether it helps a bit; the logical expressions involved are a little simpler.

Comment: I looked at the question and the statement is clearer to see when there are two variables; for some reason it makes sense. So, given the fact I chose $x=1$, which would give $1-y+z=0$. So far so good. Now, I re-read the expression with my new expression $1-y+z=0$ like you said: there exists a $y$ such that $1-y+z=0$? At this point, person $y$ would choose his number of the game, right? (I do appologize for any repetitiveness)

Comment: @Dimitri: No matter how many quantifiers there are, think of it as a game between two players, one called $\forall$ and the other, $\exists$. You’re $\exists$, and your opponent is $\forall$. You play in the order in which the quantifiers appear. If it’s $\forall\exists\forall$, he plays first, then you play, then he plays. If it’s $\forall\forall\exists$, he makes two plays, and then you get to play. His goal is to make the statement false; yours is to make it true. If you can always do so, **no matter how he makes his choices**, you win, and the statement is true. If not, you lose, and ...

Comment: ... it’s false. With $$\forall x\exists y\forall z\left(x^2-y+z=0\right)\;,$$ for instance, you cannot always make $x^2-y+z=0$ true. In fact in this case your opponent can always make it false: he picks any positive integer for $x$, and no matter what positive integer you pick for $y$, he can choose $z$ to be some positive integer **other than** $y-x^2$, thereby ensuring that $x^2-y+z$ **isn’t** $0$.

Comment: I see now. I like the idea of the game. Thank you very much for the explanation and over-clarification. I'll try to do some more using the game concept.

Comment: @Dimitri: You’re welcome. Don’t feel too bad if it takes a little while to get the hang of this: nested quantifiers are a stumbling block for quite a few students.

Comment: Yea, they're a bit tricky when more variables are added and I think most students in my class are a little confused as well...

Answer (score 1):

The original sentence says that for any $x$, there is a $y$, such that **whatever** $z$ we pick, we have $x^2-y+z=0$.

So the $y$ has to work for all $z$. But that's impossible. If it works for $z=1000$, it fails for all other $z$. The sentence is (very) false.

We **cannot** interchange the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$ without altering the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: So, in another words, whenever an Existential quantifier exists, we can always pick an arbitrary number for it and loop the rest?

Comment: The number is not necessarily arbitrary we can take account of the value of $x$ when choosing it, because the formula has the $\forall x$ **before** the $\exists y$. But if we have universal quantifiers like the $\forall z$ to the **right** of $\exists y$, we cannot change our minds about the value of $y$: it has to work for all $z$. Note that the unmodified sentence is (very) false in the integers, while your modification is true.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$\forall y. \exists x. x\text{ is the mother of }y$$ means that for every person $y$, there is some person $x$ who is $y$'s mother, which is true; every person has a mother.  But  $$\exists x.\forall y. x\text{ is the mother of }y$$ says that there is some person $x$, so that for every person $y$, $x$ is $y$'s mother, which is false; there is no person who is everyone's mother.

The order is important.