# Prove equivalence in predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have to prove that these formulas are equivalent:
$$\begin{align}
\exists x \forall y P(x,y) \equiv \forall y \exists x P(x,y) \\
\end{align}$$
Can I say that 
$$\begin{align}
\forall y \exists x P(x,y) \equiv \neg \exists x \forall y P(x,y) \\
\end{align}$$
And the result is $\neq$ ?

Comment: The formulas $\exists x \forall y P(x,y)$ and $\forall y \exists x P(x,y)$ are *not* equivalent.

Comment: Related: [Confused between Nested Quantifiers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64500/confused-between-nested-quantifiers); [Nested Quantifiers true or false](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/493102/25554)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't prove that they are equivalent because they aren't.

For example, suppose $P(x,y)$ is $x=y$. Then $\exists x\forall y(x=y)$ means that there exists something that equals everything (which is very false in a universe with more than one individual), whereas $\forall y\exists x(x=y)$ merely says that everything has *something* it is equal to (which is trivially true -- everything is equal to *itself*).

$\forall y\exists x P(x,y)$ is not equivalent to $\neg \exists x\forall y P(x,y)$ either. Here, if $P(x,y)$ means $x=x$ (that is, always true), then $\forall y\exists x P(x,y)$ is true in all worlds with at least one inhabitant, whereas $\neg\exists  x\forall y P(x,y)$ is false in all those worlds.